# Método retorna None al llamarlo desde otro script

Tags: python, django, ldap

Estoy probando una conexión LDAP y al ejecutarla desde el propio script funciona sin problemas pero al llamar el método desde otro script retorna None.

```
class Ldap:

 def user_exists():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        LDAP_URI = ''
        username = '' + ''
        password = ''
        ldap = Ldap(LDAP_URI, username, password)
        groups = ldap.get_groups()
        if groups:
            print("Usuario existe en el dominio")
            return True
        else:
            print("Usuario no existe")
            return False
```

Luego lo ejecuto en otro script y retorna None

```
import  Codeldap

test = Codeldap.Ldap
asd = test.user_exists()
print(asd)
```

Comment: Si lo llamas desde otra parte el primer if: `if __name__ == '__main__':` no se cumple, puesto que `__name__` solo es `__main__` cuando estás ejecutando el archivo directamente, con lo cual tu método no devuelve nada, ergo obtienes un `None`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá hay una explicación sencilla:

```
print('inicio script')

def saludo():
    print('hola mundo')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    print('inicio programa')
    saludo()
```

Si se ejecuta este script en modo directo, obtenemos:

```
inicio script
inicio programa
hola mundo
```

Pero al iniciarlo desde otro script con un `import`, obtenemos:

```
inicio script
```

Esto porque la condición del `if __name__ == '__main__':` solo se cumple al iniciar el script directamente. Normalmente es usado para el caso citado en mi ejemplo, en el cual tienes una función y quieres que se ejecute al ejecutar el script de forma directa, pero al importarlo desde un segundo script quieres controlar el momento de ejecución de la función y poder hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
import test

# hago cosas

# elijo el momento adecuado para ejecutar la funcion saludo
test.saludo()
```

Bueno, si tu script no tuviera la condición `if __name__ == '__main__':`, la función saludo se ejecutaría justo al importar el script y no podrías evitarlo.